# PHP and MYSQL optimized way to select by date interval

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Which is the fastest way?

a) `$query="SELECT id FROM example WHERE date_sent>='".$date1."' AND date_sent<='".$date2."'";`

or

b) `$query="SELECT id FROM example WHERE date_sent BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'";`

Also, what is faster and better if I have a date in the format '02/12/2010' ?

a) to transform in php the date to a format like '2010-12-02' and compare it directly `'WHERE date_sent>=2010-12-02'`

or

b) to use the mysql function: 
    `'WHERE date>=str_to_date('02/12/2010','%d/%m/%Y')'` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always faster to convert the date string into whatever native date format the sql server uses.  You don't have to run a convert function, nor does the server have to run a conversion.

BETWEEN is generally faster, because its handled by specific code on the backend.  Where the <= >= is generalized code and has to be tested for.  Also make sure you have proper indexes.

Use PDO too, $query = "SELECT id FROM example WHERE date_sent BETWEEN ? AND ?";

Comment: +1 for the PDO hint. I was just going to add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL manual says:

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. **This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type.**

---

> Also, what is faster and better if I have a date in the format '02/12/2010' ?

Convert that column to a `DATETIME` type or similar if it's a `VARCHAR`.